# how common is 48mb heap today?

Tags: android, heap-memory

In your experience, what is the distribution of 16mb, 24mb, 48mb in-memory heap in phones today?

Is there a 32mb heap?

Answer (score 0):

there is a 32mb heap. The G2 has one.